# Do I need to upload build folder to branch in order to make upload-artifact CI/CD work?

Tags: flutter, github-actions, firebase-app-distribution

I have been working on two separate branches

> - trunk
> - distribute

CI/CD pipelines are setup on distribute branch. When push is made to distribute branch, CI/CD workflow triggers and do the jobs listed in the main.yml file.

Here it is:

```yaml
name: Build & upload to Firebase App Distribution 

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    # This will checkout the current repo
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2.4.2

    # This will upload artifact (.apk) from your workflow
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
        name: release-apk
        path: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk

    # Distribute to Testers using Firebase App Distribution service
    - name: Firebase App Distribution
      uses: wzieba/Firebase-Distribution-Github-Action@v1.3.3
      with:
        appId: ${{secrets.FIREBASE_APP_ID}}
        token: ${{secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN}
        groups: Testers
        file: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
```

We have added /build/ in `.gitignore` so build folder won't be pushed to distribute branch. The only thing it contains is the `.github/workflow/main.yml` that will trigger the CI/CD workflow.

Now the questions is,
Do I need to remove `/build/` from `.gitignore` so my build folder will also be pushed to distribute branch where upload-artifact can pick the file from `build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk` declared in `main.yml` file?

Another question; Where does upload-artifact picks the file? Whether it picks from the current branch (in my case; build folder is not present there)? Or it picks from the current local project directory? (in my case; build folder is present)

This thing is confusing me too much :(
Thanks.

Here is the error:
[image: Note that: This CI/CD is running on distribute branch which have /build/ ignored in .gitignore file of this branch]